# Exception while reading password from a file as a Talend context variable

Tags: talend

I currently have a Talend job which reads from a context file and feeds into context variables. I have a field called `ftppassword` and store the hard coded password in the context file. I then have a context variable in the job and refer to that in my job.

With this setup my job runs fine but if I change the context file to contain a location to a password file instead of the hard coded password, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in component
tFTPConnection_1 com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPException: 530 Login
incorrect. at
com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPControlSocket.validateReply(FTPControlSocket
.java:11‌​79) at
com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.password(FTPClient.java:1844) at
com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPClient.login(FTPClient.java:1766) –
```

**Edit - 2014-12-08 **** 
Output of context parameters:
Implicit_Context_Context set key "ftphost" with value "ftp.host.com"
Implicit_Context_Context set key "ftpport" with value "21"
Implicit_Context_Context set key "ftpusername" with value "myuser"
Implicit_Context_Context set key "ftppassword" with value "/opt/password_files/DW/test1.password"
Implicit_Context_Context set key "ftpremotepath" with value "/Output/"
Implicit_Context_Context set key "ftpfilemask" with value "test_dn.zip"
Have also tried changing the data type of ftppassword to File and Password but had no luck with that.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean by password file? As in `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: Sorry i should have clarified further, i am using implicit tContextLoad.I do have a context file which contains a bunch of key value pairs (containing ftphost, ftpusername, ftpport,ftpremotepath,ftpfilemask,ftppassword etc). The use case i want is passing another file as a value to ftppassword key instead of a hardcoded password in the context file.

Comment: Isn't that file going to be hard coded too? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do so it might be better to explain exactly what you want to achieve and leave out the implementation parts.

Comment: Sure, what i want to do is reference a file in the context file for password since our Production Engineering team might just add a file at a location and give our service account permission to read from it and hence we can't hardcode it along with the other context variables.

Comment: The way we use context variable files is that we have multiple job execution servers set up for different environments. Our Talend developers are allowed to interact entirely with the development job execution servers and can provide context variable files local to the development job server. Admin users are the only ones with access to the testing and production environments and their local context variable files. We then hardcode the reference to the file as a local path to the job server so each job server uses the contexts relevant to it. Would that approach help you instead?

Comment: That is an approach i have seen been used quite frequently but i just wanted to change the scope of different context variables. Especially for this job that downloads files, i don't mind if users set up where the hdfs destination directory is etc but the password is a more secure variable and a non frequently changing one and hence i wanted to separate its location out. I am not sure why reading the password from that 
location is an issue since in another context variable i am passing the location of the ftp key and that job seems to be working fine.

Comment: I think I might have misunderstood your question. It might be worth dropping a tContextDump component at the start of your job and outputting that to a tLogRow to see what Talend is trying to read in as a contextualised password from your context file. Could you try that and edit your question to show the output of this (sanitised if you want) and how your tFTPConnection_1 is configured?

Comment: Edited the question and added screenshot of the tFTPConnection.

Comment: I think one way could be to read it via a tFileInputDelimited and setting the context.password using a tjavaRow and then going for the connection. Have tested that and it works.

Comment: I've added a third scenario to my answer which should do what you want. First you load your normal contexts using an implicit tContextLoad. One of these contexts should be the file path to a credentials/password file. You would then use this context in a tFileInputDelimited to read the credentials file and then read that into a tContextLoad to actually load the components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `implicit tContextLoad` option on the job is the equivalent of putting a tFileInputDelimited component at the start of your job with a schema of 2 columns: `key` and `value`. This is then read into a tContextLoad (hence the option name) to load the contexts in your job.

If your password file isn't in a key-value format then you can't use it this way.

The simplest option is to stick with the way you had it working before and use an `implicit tContextLoad` to load a delimited file with key-value pairs of your context variables.

Another option would be to no longer do this using the `implicit tContextLoad` option and instead to do it *explicitly*.

To do this you'd want to read in your password file using an appropriate connector such as a tFileInputDelimited. If you were reading in something that looked like `/etc/passwd` then you could split it on `:` to get:

- username
- password
- user id
- group id
- user id info
- home directory
- shell location

You could then use a tMap to populate an output schema of:

- key
- value

You would then enter `"ftppassword"` as the `key` and connect the password value to the `value` column. You'll also want to filter this record set so you only get one password being set so you might want to use something like `"ftpUser".equals(row1.username)` in the expression filter of your output table in the tMap.

Then just connect this to a tContextLoad component and your job should load the password from `/etc/passwd` for the `"ftpUser"` user account.

If you are looking to pass a file path to another file containing the password so that you can split the dependencies and allow one file to contain all the other contexts for the job but to keep the password file elsewhere then instead you'd want to pass a context variable pointing to the password file but then you'd have to explicitly consume it in the job.

In this case you may have a context file that is loaded at run time with contexts such as `ftpremotepath`, `ftphost` and `ftpfilemask` that can be set directly in the file and then a `ftpusercredentials` context variable that is a file path to a separate credentials file.

This file could then be another delimited file containing key-value pairs of context name and value such as:

```
ftpuser,myuser
ftppasswd,p4ssw0rd
```

Then at the start of your job you would explicitly read this in using a tFileInputDelimited component with a schema of 2 columns: `key` and `value`. You could then connect this to a tContextLoad component and this will load the second set of context variables into memory as well.

You could then use these as normal by referring to them as `context.ftpuser` and `context.ftppasswd`.